# python can't import PyQt5 WebKitWidgets

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pyqt5, importerror, qtwebkit

I'm running python on windows 10, and after installing PyQt5 using the command `pip install pyqt5` and after that `pip install pyqtwebkit` and everything installed. But when I do on my program `from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *` it doesn't work and outputs the following error: `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebKitWidgets: can't find specified module.`

Comment: QtWebKit is considered obsolete. Use the QtWebEngine module instead.